# Why my label is under tab bar from UITabbarController inside ViewContainer

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I just create a new project template for TabBar application in Xcode.

I arrange a storyboard to let a `UITabbarController` embedded in another view controller like this (in order to provide red header for all tab pages)

[image]

Notice that in first tab page, I put two labels on the first page. Both are locating at the top and bottom of the screen.

and here is a setting of first tab view controller.

[image]

and this is the result i have got on both device and simulator.

[image]

Why and how can my second label half shown?
i try to uncheck all options and setting

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

but none is working.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I already know what is the culprit behind this. It is the tabbar's height for ipad landscape mode normally the height is 49 but according to apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html)

They said the height will be 56 for ipad.

But in interface builder, it is always 49 and and the rootviews of my viewcontroller in each tab are calculate using this 49 height of tabbar even though i use an autolayout.

So I have a way to overcome this by create another view and let it has smaller height by 7 pixel from rootview.

But **WHY** interface builder display 49 pixel of tabbar instead of 56?

Comment: Try to embed your viewController in a navigationController and TabBarController at the same time just to see where is positioned your label. Remove code added programatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me what you are really asking, but if you simply want a red header at the top of your view controllers, you can embed them inside of an UINavigationController. Even if you still want a UITabBarController, embed every child view inside of a UINavigationController and then you can control the look of your header.

(Note: I would just add this as a comment but I don't have the reputation.)

Comment: because this is just a newly created project to simulate the problem. The real project is more complex that UINavigationController is not satisfy with the requirement. That's why i have to create a global header.