# Interface Builder Bug? Tab Bar height on iPad shows 49 instead of 56

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

According to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169546/why-my-label-is-under-tab-bar-from-uitabbarcontroller-inside-viewcontainer)

I found that the cause of the problem is Interface Builder displays wrong tab bar height.

As the title imply i saw that the tab bar height in interface builder for iPad is still 49 pixels and it also restricts my original root view to be 975 height instead of 968 and i cannot change that as in the picture below.

[image]

This causes a lot of problem since i have to create another view which has a height of 968 and use it instead of an original root view that can make some views at the bottom in the root view are half shown (some parts are behind the tab bar if i use an original root view). Otherwise, there will be a missing space of 7 pixels because interface builder thinks that it has 975 height but the actual running it has only 968 height.

So any better way to solve this?

Thanks.